# como eliminar correos de un servidor POP

Tags: java, android

chicos como elimino correos de un servidor POP.
tengo este código el cual funciona en IMAP pero POP no elimina

```
MessageIDTerm[] toDelete = maildb.getMarkAsErased();
if (toDelete.length>0){
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    Message[] mm = inbox.search(new OrTerm(toDelete));
    for (Message m :mm) {
        m.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
        maildb.deleteMail(Utils.getMessageID(m));
    }
    inbox.close(true);
}
```

Que estoy haciendo mail? :D
de antemano GRACIAS

**EDIT:**

java mail 1.4

android build tools 23.0.3

compiled android sdk 23

Comment: IMAP y POP son protocolos diferentes. Que libreria estas usando?

Comment: EDIT:

java mail 1.4

android build tools 23.0.3

compiled android sdk 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente haye una solucion
Force a un cast a POPMessage y entonces lo mando a marcar como eliminado

```
((POP3Message)m).setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
```

Comment: I think my server was little crazy because latter did it to me with the IMAP protocol :(

Comment: disculpen el ingles, creo qeu mi servidor de correos esta un poco loco porque luego me hiso lo mismo con el protocolo IMAP :(